# Smooth selecting edges

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I can't figure it out, how to properly select the trees in the following image, so it will be much smoother and realistic than in my work.

Trees:
[image]

Night sky:
[image]

My work: 
[image]

Also, it would be nice if you could tell me how to make a much more smoother transition between the night sky and the grass, so it would be close to what is it like in the "Trees" image.

Answer (score 2):

You can use channels (the blue channel) to make the sky selection easier. Just duplicate the channel, use levels/curves to increase contrast and then load it as a selection to create a layer mask.

Then you can apply a very subtle dark outer glow layer style to the masked layer in order to slightly darken the edges around the trees.

[image]

[image]

As for "blending the grass", that's kind of up to you. I have no idea what you are envisioning. Overall a bright sunny scene is rarely going to look like a night scene without some work.

Answer (score 0):

For blending the grass line, I would suggest doing the smudge and blur tool.  Experiment on separate layers so you can experiment and not ruin the original image.  But agree with the using the channels to select trees better!